# Would adding ~2 ft of copper wire to extend high voltage power supply cause problems?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I have a high voltage power supply (LabSmith HVS) that I've been using to output a in the range of 100-300V across a microfluidic channel. The cables that came with the power supply are pretty short, so they can't reach the region of an instrument I'm using to make measurements. My solution to this is going to be to wire a few feet of copper wiring through the instrument and out the back to a place where I can connect the electrodes that came with the power supply.

What this means effectively is that I plan on introducing about three feet of copper wiring to this system. Is the addition of this wiring going to impact how the voltage is applied? My intuition is that, since the effective resistance of the device I'm using is about 10 megaohms, this additional wiring would be negligible.

Side-question: My electrodes are copper wire soldered to platinum wire, which actually makes contact with salt solutions. Does applying ~100-300V have any non-negligible effects on the soldering or conductivity through the wires?

Thanks for the help.
[image: The white cables are the proprietary cables, the red is copper wiring which is soldered to platinum wires at where the joint is at the white wrapping. The goal would be to take the red wiring and wrap it around through the back of the the instrument and around so they can be attached to outside and not hanging like they are now...]

Comment: 1) The [support for that PSU](http://labsmith.com/support/hvs448-high-voltage-sequencer/) says that long leads are available. Are those the leads which are too short? 2) Can you keep the soldered joint away from the salt solution and dry?

Comment: Using the short leads, didn't anticipate needing that much length and so purchased the short ones instead. Running into issues now with manipulating them. Also, the joint is sufficiently far away from the solutions, so that shouldn't be a point of corrosion.

Comment: Photos of your setup or links to product pages of the various components would help immensely here.

Comment: I just updated it with a photo... hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Since the peak voltage of 220-230VAC mains is about 320V, and you use 300V maximum, any standard mains rated cable should work just fine. Any other wire rated for this voltage should also work (like those banana plug multimeter wires which are strewn all over the desk in most labs).

However, the manual for your supply says that it will go to 8000V. Thus the above cable shopping advice only stands if you never set it above 300V... that includes software bugs, interns, cat sleeping on the keyboard, etc...

Likewise for the connections...

The manual also says "The cables in our standard cable sets each include a 10k-Ohm resistor to protect the HVS circuits from accidental overloads and shorts."

Make sure you're aware of the resistor, voltage drop etc...

Now, your current setup is a nice way of killing someone with bare and live wires next to water... especially with a power supply capable of 8kV. You should review safety, make sure all metal that can come in contact with the solution is grounded, and keep all metal spoons and stuff like that far away from the pot!

Since the connector on the power supply side seems custom, you probably won't be able to use any cable you want. Heatshrink on your nice expensive high voltage clips would be a problem. So, purchase one or two transparent acrylic box(es), drill a hole on each end, run the wires through the holes, and make sure all the bits of exposed copper are safely **inside** the plastic box... It's easy to recover your HV clips for another experiment, and should be safe.

A transparent box makes it easy to notice if something comes off.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the wire is indeed negligible to your load. Make sure you get wire rated for your voltage, and properly connect and cover the wire, and you'll be fine.

The bare wire in your picture is just asking to shock you. Insulate with appropriately rated insulation, heatshrink, tape or connectors.

Comment: That's a good call with the bare wire part. Didn't even think about that. Thank you!